# no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source: (String)

Tags: constructor, jackson, deserialization, dropwizard

I have an entity with the following three constrcuctors

```
public MyObject() {
   // Default constructor to avoid ambiguity
  }


    public MyObject(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {

        AnotherType anothertype = new AnotherType(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        this.anotherTpe = anotherTpe;
      }

      public MyObject(AnotherType anotherType) {

        this.anotherType = anotherType;
      }
```

I then write a test to check the desrialization as fllows

@Test
  public void serializesToJSON() throws Exception {

```
final MyObject myObject =
    new MyObject(new AnotherType("arg1", "ar2", "arg3"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
assertThat(MAPPER.readValue(fixture("fixtures/myObject.json"), MyObject.class))
    .isEqualTo(myobject);
```

}

This fails with an error

```
cannot construct instance of `AnotherType` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (String)
```

I do not have control over the '`AnotherType`' object if it expects a default no args constructor in that class, if that is the issue. How should I solve this?

Some more things I tried

Tried initializing the mapper as follows

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
        .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));
```

And adding the folloiwng to the POM

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                            <arg>-parameters</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: You should look into Jackson mixins

Comment: Hmm.. Im reading about it, should the mixin class extend mYObject or AnotherType?

Comment: As I understand it, I can use mixin to override things in a 3rd party class, can I create a default constructor for the class as the error suggests? I didnt find any example to do so

Comment: You can use a mixin to add a `@JsonCreator` constructor. This is a common use case for mixins. The following link may help https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue